# NodeJS, MySQL, Express - Pluggable Modules

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

We are trying to develop a pluggable application with NodeJS and Express backed with MySQL. We are trying to achieve a pluggable framework in which there will be a `/plugins` folder that will contain custom modules. The modules will be `require()`'d based on which is active. The active / inactive state of the plugin is a simple flag in the database.

**Problem / Suggestion Needed**

The modules are properly loaded if the names of the folders are stored in a flat array and then iterated and required. Although if the same is done in an asynchronous call like a MySQL Query statement the module shows as loaded but then the routes within the module do not work. Below are the code samples

**Folder Structure**

```
./source
-node_modules/
-plugins/
 --moduleA/
   ---index.js
   ---routes/
   ---views/
 --moduleB/
   ---index.js
   ---routes/
   ---views/
-public/
-routes/
-views/
app.js
```

**Working Code**

This below code required modules perfectly and the routes / views etc. are working.

```
var plugins = ['moduleA', 'moduleB']
plugins.forEach(function(p) {
  require('./plugins/' + p)(app)
})
```

**Code Not Working**

This is how I really want, but its not working as expected. The below approach shows that the module is loaded but the routes declared in the modules don't work.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM plugins WHERE active = 1", function(err, plugins) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(plugins)
        /* plugins = [ { id: 1, plugin_name: 'moduleA', active: 1 }, { id: 2, plugin_name: 'moduleB', active: 1 } ] */
        plugins.forEach(function(p) {
            require('./plugins/' + p.plugin_name)(app)
        })
    }
})
```

**Module Code**

Here is how the code in the `moduleA/index.js` looks

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  console.log('ModuleA Loaded')
  var lead = require('./routes/view');
  app.use('/moduleA', lead);
};
```

Comment: Anny Javascript errors? And if you transpose ` plugins = [ { id: 1, plugin_name: 'moduleA', active: 1 }, { id: 2, plugin_name: 'moduleB', active: 1 } ] `  into `['moduleA', 'moduleB']` within the MySQL code approach?

Comment: @RaymondNijland; No JS errors. Also, in `forEach()` I have accessed the `plugin_name` property. So transposing or not should not matter. Also, like mentioned the `console.log()` in `moduleA` works fine.

Comment: Yes i read that the module(s) are loaded "correctly" but the routes defined in it doesn't work.. "So transposing or not should not matter"  but you are stating yourself that the `['moduleA', 'moduleB']` is working perfectly and the routes / views etc (in the question). are working so it would make logical sense to transpose like i said.

Comment: I assume the issue seems to be due to MySQL query being asynchronous and `require()` being synchronous. Although, I cannot quite point my finger to the actual issue yet.

Comment: don't think that mixing asynchronous and synchronous functions matters. The foreach won't be executed before Node.js has the MySQL results.

Comment: That's true! Will debug some more and see.